# To keep between the lines

Tags: idiom-requests

Could I say:

This woman likes to tell her stories, but at the same time KEEPS A LOT BETWEEN THE LINES ?

Comment: You could say _leaves a lot between the lines_, but using _keeps_ would only puzzle your listeners.

Comment: I knew this question [seemed familiar](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/433962/191178)...

Comment: @KarlG No, she *keeps* (to herself) because they are secret. She *leaves* (unsaid) could work when they are insignificant.

Comment: Brunna Laboissière, can you provide the broader context?

Comment: @Kris: _Keep a lot between the lines_ gets exactly one and only one Google hit. _Keeps..._ the same: this post. It's not a question of whether it's a theoretically possible construction, but that no one uses it.

Answer (score 1):

The original idiom is "read between the lines", and comes from an early method of transmitting written coded messages in invisible ink written between the lines of a document. The recipient would then learn the information by reading between the lines. (*Endangered Phrases* by Steven D. Price, 2011).

Using "between the lines" without "reading" preceding it is rare, but current  (*Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary* 3rd ed., 2012). "Keeping between the lines" is acceptable in my view, though it would be clearer and more idiomatic to say "leaving between the lines", which is less ambiguous.

Comment: See also: my comment above.